# Can I use Google Maps API for JS on my intranet-based app?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, intranet

This may have been answered elsewhere, but I still don't have enough clarification.

I am in the process of building a pledge management system for one of my charitable clients. Part of this project will involve the following:

- address auto-completion
- address validation (in my case, for imports from an old system only)
- address component splitting (fields for street #, name, suburb, city, etc)

Now, the Google Maps API (v3) for JS has everything I need to proceed. However, I am not sure if I am able to use it as the app itself is designed for an intranet. Furthermore, the app is not publicly accessible. Only employees with an employee ID/key can access the app.

So, does this mean that I cannot use the API, simply because the app cannot be accessed by the public? If that is the case, what other services offer the above functionality that will allow me to?

(I do apologise if I am not supposed to be asking this question here - I don't know where else to put it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Maps/Places API inside of an Intranet needs the Premier API version. You can take a look at [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) as an alternative, but you will need to [run your own Nominatim server](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation), since the usage policy for the public OSM Nominatim server forbids the sort of traffic features like auto-completion would generate.

Comment: I see. And can Nominatim be used on Windows (that is, without a VM)?

Comment: It can only run on Ubuntu/Debian or CentOS